# Current MongoDB server time in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

How do I get the MongoDB's time or use it in a query from VB.NET?

For example, in the Mongo shell I would do:

```
db.Cookies.find({ expireOn: { $lt: new Date() } });
```

In PHP I can easily do something like this:

```
$model->expireOn = new MongoDate();
```

How do I approach this in VB.Net?  I don't want to use the local machine's time.  This obviously doesn't work...

```
MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.LT("expireOn", "new Date()")
```

Comment: Is `DateTime.UtcNow` on one of your web servers really that much worse an option than the Utc time from *one of* the database servers in the cluster?  There will be clock drift between your servers (web and database), you need to handle that regardless.  Which server generated the `expireOn` value that you are concerned about comparing against?

Comment: The VB application will be running on a client computer. I'd just prefer to use the server's time.

I've found a solution for the time being...

`MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.LT("expireOn", database.Eval(EvalFlags.None, "function() { return new Date(); }"))`

but it seems inefficient.

Comment: While `eval` might work, it's a big security risk to leave `eval` open, as any arbitrary command can be run against the MongoDB (including deleting all data for example). http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval  You'd be better off just having a tiny web service available on the same server that you could call to fetch the current time.

Comment: (And since you're using the .NET driver, you can't rely on ObjectIDs which normally contain the time of creation, as the .NET driver creates them locally on the client when they're not present rather than the DB server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merely want to remove expired cookies from your collection, you could use the [TTL collection feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) which will automatically remove expired entries using a background worker on the server, hence using the server's time:

```
db.Cookies.ensureIndex( { "expireOn": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

If you really need to query, use a service program that runs on the server or ensure your clocks are reasonably synchronized because clocks that are considerably off can cause a plethora of problems, especially for web servers and email servers. (Consider HTTP headers like `Date`, `LastModified` and `If-Modified-Since`, Email Timestamps, HMAC/timestamp validation against replay attacks, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm actually looking for documents that need to be updated, not removed. I wasn't clear on that in my description though.

Comment: I'll give it to you since it resolves the problem I described. I'm still using my solution though. :)